# Materialize's Parallax causing Boostrap's Modals/Collapse disappearance on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a website for a local business in my area, but I found a issue on Chrome and after extensive googling I haven't found anyone else with it. The page works perfectly on Firefox and IE, but fails in Chrome.

The page:

http://elsolsaleparatodos.mx/

The issue:

Modals (Click a white circle with green drawings in the parallax to toggle) flicker above the parallax, or disappear instantly. This also happens with the mobile collapse menu. When the screen is resized making the collapse menu appear, open said menu and scroll down until a parallax comes into the viewport, the menu then disappears.

What I have come with so far:
Commenting the `$('.parallax').parallax();` line on app.css fixes the issue, but breaks the parallax of course.

I have tried: 
- Changing materialize.min.js to the newest materialize.js 
- Checking for loading any plugin twice 
- Reading the materialize's parallax function for any... anormalities.

I haven't even found a remote lead, and the issue is non-existent in any other browser so I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find the *source* of the problem or *why* it was only present in Chrome, but I fixed it by adding the following code to my CSS:

```
.modal {
     overflow: visible !important;
}
```

The modal has stopped flickering and now functions correctly.